# Running the same crontab twice in a minute

Tags: scrapy, cron

When I run my spider in scrapy, manually, in the first time it executes the code but gives me 0 results. Yet, when I run it second time, then it crawls perfectly. This is fine when I do it manually, but when I run it in crontab, it does not produce any result. I get this (I deleted the time data):

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 221,
'downloader/request_count': 1,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
'downloader/response_bytes': 116972,
'downloader/response_count': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(xxx, x, xxx, xx, xx, xx, xxxx),
'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'log_count/WARNING': 1,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
```

When I run it manually I receive 9 results:

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4696,
'downloader/request_count': 10,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 10,
'downloader/response_bytes': 202734,
'downloader/response_count': 10,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 10,
'dupefilter/filtered': 9,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(xxx, x, xx, xx, xx, xx, xxxxxx),
'item_scraped_count': 9,
'log_count/DEBUG': 21,
'log_count/INFO': 8,
'log_count/WARNING': 1,
'request_depth_max': 2,
'response_received_count': 10,
'scheduler/dequeued': 10,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 10,
'scheduler/enqueued': 10,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 10,
```

What do I wrong?

And, if I run the same crontab job second time within a minute will it produce the results? If so how do I that?

Answer (score -1):

Can you show full command how do you run in cron?
Also try to add -L DEBUG to crawl command to see more.

Comment: I run the same command twice from terminal. In the first time, I gave me the result 1 (from the original question) and in the second time, it gave me the result 2 (from the original question); the code I run is this:
    "scrapy crawl spiderTest -o CrawlTest1.csv". The same thing also happens in cron, for 3-4 times it does not work, and then it produces results.

Comment: Please run it as ```scrapy crawl spiderTest -L DEBUG -o CrawlTest1.csv``` and try to check logs

Comment: That produced the exact same result, and I couldn't find any difference in the logs.

Comment: I'm afraid, w/o looking into logs / code - hard to advice you more